# How to run Spark on Docker using bitnami docker-compose?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm trying to run spark with bitnami docker-compose

```html
version: '2'

services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
  spark-worker-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
```

I'm able to run spark job when I attach to the container, but I'm unable to create a spark session from the host itself

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://localhost:7077").appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

I also tried with the container ip:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://172.19.0.4:7077").appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

but anything I try I'm getting the same error:

```
JAVA_HOME is not set
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

what am I doing wrong?
OS is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: From inside the container, you should be using `.master(os.environ['SPARK_MASTER_URL'])`, but I dont think that'll fix `JAVA_HOME` not being set

Comment: If you're trying to run from outside of Docker, you need to install Java... So, would be best if you did exec into the containers if you cannot do that

Comment: I think that's the reason, you need java in your host.

Comment: yes, installing java on my host solved that issue.
thanks a lot

Comment: @lc14 Hi! I have the same problem, how did you solve this? I mean, how did you install java and which version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Tavis, I installed Java 11 you can run 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk 
to do so, 
I also added the following configurations to SparkConf :

('spark.master', 'spark://host_ip:7077'),
('spark.app.name', 'appname'),
('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
('spark.driver.bindAddress', 'driver_ip_address'),
('spark.driver.host', 'driver_ip_address'),

then I was able to run my pyspark job located on the driver_ip_address, using the spark cluster running on docker

Comment: @lc14 So, in order to run your pyspark job, the driver_ip_address is the address from which you run the spark cluster? And the host_ip is the one from which you run the pyspark code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tavis the ip address in spark.master is the ip of the spark master (which is obviously part of the cluster), and I used the ip address of the machine with python files for both 
spark.driver.bindAddress and spark.driver.host

so to make it more clear: 
('spark.master', 'spark://192.168.1.55:7077'),
('spark.driver.bindAddress', '192.168.1.22'),
('spark.driver.host', '192.168.1.22'),

spark cluster is using 192.168.1.55 as the master, and my python code is on 192.168.1.22

hope I didn't make a mess